# in asp.net mvc, how can I pass an array of integers as a parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, arrays

i have a controller function that previously had integers as each section in the URL (which i setup in the routing file) but now one of the parameters needs to be an array of integers.  Here is the controller action:

```
    public JsonResult Refresh(string scope, int[] scopeId)
    {
        return RefreshMe(scope, scopeId);
    }
```

in my javascript, i had the below but i now need to get scopeId to be an integer array.
how can i setup up a url to post to using jquery, javascript

```
   var scope = "Test";
   var scopeId = 3;

  // SCOPEID now needs to be an array of integers

  $.post('/Calendar/Refresh/' + scope + '/' + scopeId, function (data) {
        $(replacementHTML).html(data);
        $(blockSection).unblock();
  }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following should do the job:

```
var scope = 'Test';
var scopeId = [1, 2, 3];

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Refresh", "Calendar")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { scope: scope, scopeId: scopeId },
    traditional: true,
    success: function(result) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

and if you are using ASP.NET MVC 3 you could also send the request as a JSON object:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Refresh", "Calendar")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ scope: scope, scopeId: scopeId }),
    success: function(result) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from jquery's API for $.post()

Example: pass arrays of data to the server (while still ignoring the return results).

```
$.post("test.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] }, function() { //do stuff });
```

Comment: I don't think the `[]` in `choices[]` is needed.

Comment: @Omar It was the example on the jQuery site.  Just a cut/paste job.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/