# Array of integers as value for an option in a html select

Tags: html, arrays, asp.net-mvc-3, html-select

i have a question about the `<option>` of a `<select>` tag in my mvc3 c# application.
Can i pass an array of ints to an action using a `<option>` tag?
I mean, something like this:

```
<select name="status_filter">
   <option value="1,2,3,4">All</option>
   <option value="2,3">Some</option>
   <option value="2">One</option>
</select>
```

and in my action method:

```
public ActionResult Filter(int[] status_filter)
```

Can be done?

Thanks,
Gonzalo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have to change the array for a string that say's "all", "some", "one" and then on the controller perform a switch.

Answer (score 0):

By default this will not bind. You will need a custom model binder OR pass it as an array in javascript

From: 
[in asp.net mvc, how can I pass an array of integers as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785428/in-asp-net-mvc-how-can-i-pass-an-array-of-integers-as-a-parameter)

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Refresh", "Calendar")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ scope: scope, scopeId: scopeId }),
    success: function(result) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Or use your own model binder:

http://neimke.blogspot.com/2011/01/pass-array-of-integers-to-controller.html