# Array Passed to Controller Received as NULL

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using `$.post()` to post an array of integer values to my controller.

Here's how I construct my array:

```
var ratings = [];
$('#ratings input[name=newReviewRatings]').each(function () {
    ratings.push($(this).val());
});
```

Here's how I'm posting it to the controller:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("CreateReview", "Provider")',
{
    id: providerId,
    ratings: ratings,
    comment: comment
});
```

Here's the form data that gets posted:

> {id=437baf29-4196-4966-88de-a8fde87ef68d&ratings%5b%5d=1&ratings%5b%5d=2&ratings%5b%5d=3&ratings%5b%5d=4&ratings%5b%5d=5&comment=Comments}

And here's my controller signature:

```
public ActionResult CreateReview(Guid id, int[] ratings, string comment)
{
    // ....
}
```

That seems like that should be right, but `ratings` is always null. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

I also tried `string[] ratings` and got the same result. I also saw a suggestion to pass the array using `JSON.stringify(ratings)` but that didn't seem to help either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [in asp.net mvc, how can I pass an array of integers as a parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785428/in-asp-net-mvc-how-can-i-pass-an-array-of-integers-as-a-parameter)

Comment: @BNL No offense but I don't think this is an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In adition to converting the post data to json, you can also set the `traditional` param to true. This will cause jQuery to use the correct post format for MVC.

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

$.post('@Url.Action("CreateReview", "Home")',
    {
        id: 'GUID STRING HERE',
        ratings: [1, 2, 3],
        comment: 'adfef'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify contentType like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url:url,
  type:"POST",
  data:data,
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(){
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: Only if you convert the data to json first.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. But I was able to get it working by setting `data` to `JSON.stringify({ id: providerId, ratings: ratings, comment: comment })`.